# How do you do backwards elimination with mixture of categorical and quantitative variables?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, categorical-data, stepwise-regression

So I have a regression model with a couple of quantitative variables and several categorical variables.
Should I just focus first on seeing if the quantitative variables are significant predictors for the dependent variable by using the summary(..) command and looking at the p-value, and, after that, use an ANOVA comparing the reduced model without one of the categorical predictors and compare it to the full model (both models without the insignificant quantitative predictors) for each categorical predictor and omit where necessary?

Comment: Note that a Wald test can be carried out for the null hypothesis that a set of coefficients are all equal to zero.